# trouble overlapping divs in asp.net using float

Tags: html, css

aspx:

```
<div id="home_tabs" CssClass="home_tabs" runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ClientIDMode="static" Text="Cures" 
                        ID="cures_btn" CssClass="home_tab" runat="server" onclick="cures_btn_Click" />
                    <div id="home_tabs_line" CssClass="home_tabs_line" runat="server"></div>
                </div>
```

css:

```
.home_tab 
{
    vertical-align: top !important;
    height: 46px;
    padding: 0px 15px !important;
    line-height: 46px !important;
    background: #cecece !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;   
    color: #000 !important;
    border: solid #fff 1px !important;
    border-bottom-width: 0px !important;
    margin-right: 10px !important;
    padding-left: 50px !important;
    z-index: 10;
}

.home_tabs_line 
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 1px;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.home_tabs {
   height: 46px;
}
```

I would like the home_tabs_line to go under the home_tab div. I gave them z-indexes and floated the line left. Why are they not overlapping?

Comment: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed) http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Thanks, that does not seem to fix the issue though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the outer div's position as relative and the inner ones as absolute to make z-index work properly.

After that all of the inner divs' **bottom**, **top**, **left** and **right** values will position the divs according to the outer div. With the **bottom:0** you can stick the line to the bottom of the outer div. To do this you must remove the **margin-bottom** property or use its value as **bottom**'s value.

CSS:

```
.home_tab 
{
    vertical-align: top !important;
    height: 46px;
    padding: 0px 15px !important;
    line-height: 46px !important;
    background: #cecece !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;   
    color: #000 !important;
    border: solid #fff 1px !important;
    border-bottom-width: 0px !important;
    margin-right: 10px !important;
    padding-left: 50px !important;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute; /*ADDED*/
}

.home_tabs_line 
{
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 1px;
    z-index: 0;
    /*margin-bottom: 10px;*/ /*DELETED*/
    position: absolute; /*ADDED*/
    bottom:0; /*ADDED*/
}

.home_tabs {
    position:relative; /*ADDED*/
    background-color: red;
    height: 46px;
}
```

See the fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/vg2rpd7k/